# Backup RPI but not wohle disk

Tags: raspberry-pi, backup, dd

I use a Backup-Script which uses `dd`. I have switched from SD to SSD via USB (120GB) and now the backup is 120GB. Is it possible to back up only sda1 and sda2?

```
root@raspberrypi# lsblk -l
NAME MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda    8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
sda1   8:1    0   256M  0 part /boot
sda2   8:2    0  14.6G  0 part /
```

Comment: a bit copy of a disk or partition (e.g. using `dd`) will **always** copy the entire disk or partition, no matter how much space is actually used in the filesystem.   If you only want to backup the files, use a file-copying program like `cp` or `tar` or, best of all, `rsync`.

Comment: @cas the OP wants  to copy a partition (`sda1` and `sda2`) just not the entire drive (`sda`). Steffen, yes, it is possible but we cannot help you modify a script you don't show us. Please [edit] your question and show us the backup script you use.

Comment: 1) looks to me as if not all disk is occupy, e.g. 96G seems wasted. 2) `dd` is a poor choice for backup of live filesystem.

Comment: As others stated, using `dd` to make backups is a poor choice in this case. You may want to find a backup package that gives you precise control over what/when/how to/where to backup. Especially when using SDD drives--You will want to reduce backups to only the parts of the source drive which have changed. SDD drives have a limited "write" lifetime, so you only want to send writes to it when necessary.